# php regular expression assistance bold a filename

Tags: php, expression

I am not very good, with regular expression in php I am trying to get a reg_expression to find all file names such as **/file-name-here.php** and make it bold.

This expression works in Flash but not in php it also doesn't accept the '-' i'm not sure why i can't get it to work with preg_replace

```
/(https?://)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\b\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2})?((/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?(\.[a-z]*)?/g
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape your forward slashes:

```
/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\b\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2})?((\/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?(\.[a-z]*)?/g
```

Or you could use a different delimiter (in PHP, the first character is the delimiter for the regular expression):

```
@(https?://)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\b\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2})?((/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?(\.[a-z]*)?@g
```